# Aurelia CLI adding script reference to node_modules folder

Tags: aurelia

I am attempting to add the `aurelia-validation` plugin to my app. In my `aurelia.json` file, I have added the module to the `dependencies` node.

```
    "prepend": [
      "node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.core.js",
      "node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/resources/scripts/configure-bluebird.js",
      "node_modules/requirejs/require.js"
    ],
    "dependencies": [
      ... Trimmed other packages...
      {
        "name": "aurelia-validation",
        "main": "aurelia-validation",
        "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-validation/dist/amd",
        "resources": []
      }
    ]
```

When I look at the index.html file in the browser, I see a script tag in the `<head>` pointing to aurelia-validation in the node_modules folder.

[image: Script link to aurelia-validation]

Which is causing a run time error because that path does not exist in my web root.

[image: Error loading aurelia-validation]

Why is the CLI referencing this module like this? Why would it not bundle it like the rest of my files?

Comment: Have you tried using `au import` to handle adding dependecies in aurelia.json? See it [here](http://blog.aurelia.io/2017/03/07/early-march-mega-release/).

Comment: have you definitely "npm install"-ed aurelia-validation into your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time you can achieve installing/adding reference in aurelia.json using `au import/install`. See it [here](http://blog.aurelia.io/2017/03/07/early-march-mega-release/).

Comment: Im not certain if I forgot to npm install something or had the order in my aurelia.json wrong. I reinstalled everything using au install and it fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: In some case I ran into issues that bootstrap can't load because of jquery. Also note that it is important the order in which the plugins appear in dependencies.